# How to best check integrity of nvarchar fields that have been exported to xlsx files comparing to the view results?

Tags: sql

I am using this code to check for data integrity of nvarchar/string data fields.  Taking the sum from the view using code below, and comparing that to similar formula in EXCEL to see if I get the same total. Is there a better way? I am new at this.

```
--Aggregate Boolean fields e.g. nvarchar. 
With table1 AS
(
Select 
       CASE WHEN (field_name) = 'Y' Then 1
            WHEN field_name = 'N' Then 2
            When field_name IS NULL THEN 3 
            ELSE field_name
            END AS field_name_count
From mysqlview
)
Select SUM(field_name) AS Count
From table1 
;
```

Or this approach

```
 --Count characters in nvarchar column
Select 
       SUM(LEN(field_name)) AS Count
From mysqlview
;
```

Comment: The first idea is good. If there are just few different strings, you can give every string a number and then sum up those numbers. (Your `else` doesn't work, because the case expression must return a number. Use `ELSE 4` there. And there is a typo later where `SUM(field_name)` must be `SUM(field_name_count)` of course.) Not being a mathematician, I suppose you'd get an even more reliable checksum, were the numbers not that close together, e.g. Y = 1000000, NULL = 10000, N = 100, ELSE = 1.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The second method is good for many different strings of different lengths. (If the column contains only or mainly single characters like Y, N, etc. it doesn't work well of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll add my 2 cents here.
you seems to sum a Nvarchar field - can you update your question with the reasoning for this?

Also - in the first example you have sum on 'field_name' while the column name is 'field_name_count'

Do you try to see how many fields contain text and compare this number to your Excel data?

in that case you can count them easily by doing:
select count(1) from mysqlview where fieldname != '' and not fieldname is null

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks.  I am using sum for the nvarchar fields b/c I am trying to make sure that I have not lost any data in the view export process.  I can check the numerical columns to see if their sums match in the view and also in the Excel file.  Not really knowing how best to compare text fields I tried to convert the text a number so I can sum it to see if my sums are the same.  If I don't get any errors then I know with some degree of certainty that all my text came through the CSV as text and not something else.  The files are kinda big.

Comment: If I understand you are exporting from excel and you want to validate that the export works as expected?

Comment: What method do you use? And why do you feel you need to validate it? Are you using bcp? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15